# Using Javascript to change background image of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been struggling with my Javascript skills using my books to get through it but I've finally found something that I can't seem to cobble together with just the books alone. What I'm trying to do is change the css background-image of a div with an id of belowNav every couple-few seconds below is the code I have that is returning no errors in the console but effectively not functioning(literally not doing anything) If someone with more JS skills than I could help it would be much appreciated :)

```
    setInterval(function changeImage(){
    var el = document.getElementById("belowNav");
    var currentImage = 0;
    var backImage = ["img2.png",
                        "IMG_3880.JPG",
                        "IMG_6629.JPG",
                        "IMG_6552.JPG",
                        "IMG_4090.JPG",
                        "IMG_0005.JPG",
                        "IMG_0041.JPG",
                        "IMG_6544.JPG",
                        "IMG_6628.JPG",
                        "IMG_5168.JPG",
                        "coffee.jpg"]
    var lastImage = backImage.length+1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++); {
    currentImage = i;
    el.style.backgroundImage = "%resource("+backImage[currentImage]+")%";
        if(i == 10){
        i = 0
            }//end if
        }//end for
    }, 2000);//end Function
```

Comment: What's `"%resource("`? Also, do you realize that your for loop runs completely each time your changeImage is executed?

Comment: add `;` after `"coffee.jpg"]`

Comment: should it be "url("+backImage[currentImage]+")"?

Comment: thanks for the quick replies, the %resource is how(according to the internet) rapidweaver finds it resources without the user having to use '../' or '/' at all. kinda neat but seems fragile from a code aspect. added the ; and the url, waiting on push to see if it fixed it.

Comment: its a mac-only IDE that claims code-free development. Very cool but if you want things that look good to happen you have to invest a bunch of money in plugins and stacks. *bleck* I prefer code but my bosses rather have me use it because its faster than coding. this is an issue with making a site look super good and this is the only way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a few modifications to your code.

Primarily, your code loops from 0 to 10 upon *each call* to the `changeImage` function. It seems that you want to advance the image index only *once per call*, in order to change the background to the next image in the array.

I've used `url()` for the background image, per [CSS `background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

I've also moved variable definitions outside of the function, as they do not need to be redefined upon each call.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("belowNav"),
  backImage = [
    "https://via.placeholder.com/400x150?text=One",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/400x150?text=Two",
    "https://via.placeholder.com/400x150?text=Three"
  ],
  imageIndex = 0;


function changeImage() {
  el.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + backImage[imageIndex] + "')";
  imageIndex++;
  if (imageIndex >= backImage.length) {
    imageIndex = 0;
  }
}

setInterval(changeImage, 2000);
changeImage();
```

```css
div#belowNav {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="belowNav"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there! The CSS background property is wrapped within a url('') wrapper, so this line:

```
el.style.backgroundImage = "%resource("+backImage[currentImage]+")%";
```

Should be

```
el.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+backImage[currentImage]+"')";
```

I wasn't sure what %resource is referring to, so I removed those references. Credit to imnancysun for writing this first though!

Comment: It sees that the code has other issues, as well. It still does not function as expected.